# Jquery Bootstrap Datepicker disable past dates and don't autofill input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using jquery bootstrap datepicker from [source](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I need to disable past dates, and also don't want the picker to auto fill the input box.

Hence I used the below code:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     format: 'L',
     minDate: new Date(),
     useCurrent: false,
 });
```

However on using this, it disables todays date also. I figured out that this was due to `useCurrent: false` but on commenting this line it auto fills the input box. How can I block past dates by not blocking todays date and also avoid auto fill at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

simple create yesterday date : and pass it as argument

```
yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);

jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     format: 'L',
     minDate: yesterday,
     useCurrent: false,
});
```